# How can I make casperjs repeat a loop until a certain condition is met?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to get casperjs working with the following situation:

> A web page loads, then within that page, it ajax loads data items
>   along with a 'read more' button which in turn loads some more data
>   items.

I need the script to recursively check if the 'read more' button exists (as there are many data items to load), if so, click it, else continue with the rest of the script and output the full page as a jpeg.

I've tried by writing the code below, but it doesn't loop as I had hoped. It just clicks the button once, then outputs the image, even though more data loads, and the button still exists for clicking again.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose : true,
    logLevel : 'debug',
    pageSettings : {
        "userAgent" : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1262.0 Safari/537.10',
        "loadImages" : false,
        "webSecurityEnabled" : false,
        "ignoreSslErrors" : true
    },
});

var urls = {
    login : 'http://www.website.com/login',
    details : 'http://www.website.com/details',
};

casper.start(urls.login, function() {

    //login stuff

});

//the function I'm trying to recursively loop before moving on to saving the capture image
function checkMore() {

    //check to see if the 'read more' button exists
    if (casper.exists('a.read-more')) {

        //click the button to load more items           
        casper.click('a.read-more');

        //wait for the items to load, then run the check again
        casper.wait(3000, function() {
            casper.run(checkMore);
        });

    }

}

casper.thenOpen(urls.details, function() {

    //wait for the page along with ajax items to load shortly after
    this.wait(3000, function() {
        this.run(checkMore);
    });

});

casper.then(function() {

    //output the result
    this.capture('output.jpg');

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: I think you should only call `run` once. You can just pass `checkMore` directly to the wait function, ie. `this.wait(3000, checkMore)`. However, in `checkMore` the `this` reference won't work - so you'll have to write eg. `casper.exists('...')`.

Comment: Have you considered `waitForSelector` for waiting for the `read-more` button? It seems like a good fit for this scenario. http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitforselector

Comment: How does it loop? You haven't described what the problem is.

Comment: @pius Both of your comments together make an answer. Go on then. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pius had the right idea, I modified my code, the solution is below.

```
var urls = {
    login : 'http://www.website.com/login',
    details : 'http://www.website.com/details',
};

casper.start(urls.login, function() {

    //login stuff

});

//the function I'm trying to recursively loop before moving on to saving the capture image
function checkMore() {

    //check to see if the 'read more' button exists
    if (casper.exists('a.read-more')) {

        //click the button to load more items           
        casper.click('a.read-more');

        //wait for the items to load, then run the check again
        casper.wait(3000, checkMore);

    }

}

casper.thenOpen(urls.details, function() {

    //wait for the page along with ajax items to load shortly after
    this.wait(3000, checkMore);

});

casper.then(function() {

    //output the result
    this.capture('output.jpg');

});

casper.run();
```

Comment: what happens if `a.readmore` never becomes visible? Shouldn't you consider this?

Comment: Rippo, that is why I check with "if (casper.exists('a.read-more'))". if the link never existed, or if the link has stopped showing, then the script won't click, nor call the checkMore function again.

Comment: and if the ajax call fails?

Comment: My initial question was primarily based upon how to get a loop working until a certain condition is met, which in my case was for a button to appear. rather than how to bullet proof against ajax fails, as that wasn't really a concern in my case!

Comment: glad it doesn't apply in your case.